# How to remove duplicate entries in SQL using selected columns only?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data is as shown below:

```
id    | name   | date        | country   | vendor
1717  | CUST A | 8-Aug-1978  | INDIA     | VENDOR 1
1972  | CUST B | 1-Jan-1965  | INDIA     | VENDOR 2
2083  | CUST C | 1-Jan-1936  | AUSTRALIA | VENDOR 1
2189  | CUST D | 27-May-2000 | USA       | VENDOR 4
2189  | CUST D | 27-May-2000 | USA       | VENDOR 5
2189  | CUST D | 27-May-2000 | USA       | VENDOR 6
```

Question:
I want to remove the duplicate rows based on Columns 
id, name, date, gender and country only (hence excluding Vendor)

In the above example, the 5th and 6th entries are duplicate except for their vendors.

Using Select Query how can I get rid of the 5th and 6th entry and keep on 4th entry?

By Keeping the 4th Entry, I mean the first Entry that comes up by select in the sequence of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is `group by`:

```
select id, name, date, gender, country, min(vendor) as vendor
from t
group by id, name, date, gender, country;
```

This returns an "arbitrary" value of vendor.  Tables in SQL represent *unordered* sets.  There is no concept of 4th or 5th or 6th row.  So, if you want one of the particular vendor values, you need to specify how that value is determined.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(vendor) as count, id, name, date, gender, country 
FROM TABLENAME 
GROUP BY id, name, date, gender, country
WHERE Count > 1
```

[sql](/questions/tagged/sql)[csa](/questions/tagged/csa)

Comment: Did you even try to execute it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in preserving the `vendor` information, you can use the `distinct` keyword

```
select distinct id, name, date, gender, country
from   yourTable
```

This way the rows that are different for the undesired column only, will result as identical and the `distinct` will have the query return only one of them

**Edit**

If you want to preserve only the rows that are not duplicate, you can first select the combinations of id, name, date, gender and country that are available only once

```
select  id, name, date, gender, country, count(*)
from    yourTable
group by id, name, date, gender, country
having count(*) = 1
```

Then you use this table to filter the original one, by joining them together

```
select  t1.*
from    yourTable t1
join    (
            select  id, name, date, gender, country, count(*)
            from    yourTable
            group by id, name, date, gender, country
            having count(*) = 1
        ) t2
on      t1.id = t2.id and
        t1.name = t2.name and
        t1.date = t2.date and
        t1.gender = t2.gender and
        t1.country = t2.country
```

Comment: OP mentioned, *keep on 4th entry*. Looks like OP wants all the columns just not the duplicate records

Comment: @Prdp You might be right, I edited my answer with a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row_Number()

```
select * from (
select *, RowN= Row_Number() over(partition by id, name, date, gender, country order by id, name, date, gender, country) 
    from YourTable ) a where a.RowN = 1
```